# Jquery dialog close button title overlays close icon

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm having issue with the close button in jQuery dialog. Somehow the title of the button didnt get hidden and overlays on the icon [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EEHz.png).

I inspect the element and this is what I got [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uql8.png)

What's rendered in the _Layout.cshtml

```
<head>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/AboutContactUs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/userPage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/home.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/resizable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/selectable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/accordion.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/button.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    ....
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ajax-popup.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here's how I set up the dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    ....
    $("#addSuccessDialog").dialog({
        height: 100,
        width: 200,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true
    });
    var popupDialog = function (e) {
        $("#addSuccessDialog").dialog("open");
    }

    // the return viewed has many add buttons, each button is registered with the handler above.
    $("#giftSearchButton").click(function (e) {
        $("#ajaxLoader").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'testAmazon',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ cat: $("#EventGiftViewModal_selectedCategory").val(), kw: $("#EventGiftViewModal_keyWord").val(), tabContentWidth: tabContentWidth }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (e) {
                $("#ajaxLoader").hide();
                $("#giftSearchResult").empty();
                $("#giftSearchResult").html(e);
                $(".addGift-primary").each(function () {
                    $(this).click(popupDialog);
                })
            }
        });
    });
    ....
});
```

Comment: I was unable to replicate the results. Tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/r2a6d3kp/ Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using closeText option got rid of this weird behavior...

```
$("#addSuccessDialog").dialog({
    closeText:"",
    height: 100,
    width: 200,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true
});
```

https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-closeText